# I'm not getting the exact answer.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,t)$ satisfy the IVP $u_{t}=u_{xx}$,$x\in \mathbb{R},t>0$  and $$u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
  1, & x\in[0,1]\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ Then the value of $$\lim_{t\to 0^+} u(1,t)$$ is

1. $e$
2. $\pi$
3. $\frac{1}{2}$
4. $1$

My efforts: I have three solution of the given problem

$$u(x,t)=(ax+b)$$

$$u(x,t)=(ae^{kx}+be^{-kx})ce^{k^2t}$$

$$u(x,t)=(a\cos(kx)+b\sin(kx))ce^{-k^2t}$$

Now,  how can I apply boundary conditions to get the answer?
Answer is 3.

Comment: In the last one you should change $\cos$ and $\sin$ to $\cosh$ and $\sinh$.

Comment: $cosh$ and $sinh$ not possible because when the separation constant will be negative so will get complex roots $-ki , ki$ ,so the solution will be form of $sin$ and $cos$

Comment: You are right. I messed something up. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The general answer of the heat equation is as follows:$$u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\omega^2t}\Big(A(\omega)\cos\omega x+B(\omega)\sin\omega x\Big)$$with$$A(\omega)={1\over \pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,0)\cos\omega xdx\\B(\omega)={1\over \pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,0)\sin\omega xdx$$now if we assume an **even expansion of $u(x,0)$ around $x=0$** we obtain$$B(\omega)=0\\A(\omega)={2\over\pi}\int_0^1\cos\omega xdx={2\sin\omega\over \pi\omega}$$therefore by substitution$$u(x,t)={2\over \pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-\omega^2 t}{\sin\omega\over\omega}\cos\omega xdx$$